# Azure pipelines task VSTest@2 failing with error - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.resources'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I’ve created .Net Core 3.1 API test case projects. My project has the following nugget packages.

> - Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk 15.3.0
> - Moq 4.16.1
> - xunit - 2.4.1
> - xunit.runner.visualstudio - 2.4.3

The unit test project executes properly in VS 2019 and all my test cases are passed. In the deployment yaml file, I’ve the following code.

```
- task: VSTest@2
 - inputs:
     platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
     configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

This task fails with tons of errors

```
2021-03-03T18:33:16.4990294Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.resources.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.resources.dll. Reason:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.resources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
2021-03-03T18:33:16.5032225Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.resources.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\cs\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.resources.dll. Reason:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.resources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
2021-03-03T18:33:16.5033961Z [MSTest][Discovery][D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll] Failed to discover tests from assembly D:\a\1\s\API\MyProject.ApiTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\de\Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources.dll. Reason:Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TestPlatform.CommunicationUtilities.resources' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

and so on.

I tried upgrading/downgrading Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk versions, but no luck. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In our projects, we do a couple of things: make sure the right tool set is installed, and be specific about the test path:

```yaml
          - task: VisualStudioTestPlatformInstaller@1
            displayName: 'Install Visual Studio Test Platform'
            inputs:
              packageFeedSelector: 'nugetOrg'
              versionSelector: 'latestStable'
          - task: VSTest@2
            displayName: 'Run Unit Tests'
            inputs:
              vsTestVersion: 'toolsInstaller'    
              # our test projects all have ".Tests" in the name
              testAssemblyVer2: '**/bin/$(buildConfiguration)/*.Tests.dll'
              platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
              configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
              codeCoverageEnabled: true
              runTestsInIsolation: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from WaitingForGuacamole worked along with an upgrade to Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk to 16.9.1. Thanks.